# Dictionary JSON Formatting

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a .NET dictionary containing items from a SQL Function in Entity Framework. Here is my code to add the items to a dictionary:

```
    public FooViewModel GetFoo()
    {

        var fooresults = new FooResultsViewModel();

        using (var db = new DBEntities())
        {
            var results = db.FunctionResults().ToList();
            foreach (var d in results)
            {
                foo.a.Add(d.ColumnName, d.ColumnValue);
            }


        }
        return fooresults;
```

Here is my model:

```
public class FooViewModel : GraphViewModel
{
    public FooResultsViewModel() { }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> a = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
}
```

Finally here is my controller:

```
    public virtual JsonResult GetData()
    {
        var fooresults = new FactSurveryResultsQueries().GetAverages();
        return new JsonResult { JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, Data = fooresults };
    }
```

And this is the JSON that is returned:

```
{"a":
{"FooResult1":3.579831,
"FooResult2":3.359243,
"FooResult3":3.720588,
"FooResult4":3.636554,
"FooResult5":3.285714,
"FooResult6":3.758403,
"FooResult7":3.262605}}
```

However I am looking for something that returns like:

```
{"a":
{ColumnName:"FooResult1", 
ColumnValue:3.579831,
ColumnName:"FooResult2",
ColumnValue:3.359243,
ColumnName:"FooResult3",
ColumnValue:3.720588,
ColumnName:"FooResult4",
ColumnValue:3.636554,
ColumnName:"FooResult5",
ColumnValue:3.285714,
ColumnName:"FooResult6",
ColumnValue:3.758403,
ColumnName:"FooResult7",
ColumnValue:3.262605}}
```

Is there a way to format the JSON output for the second result?

Comment: FYI, it's a .NET dictionary, not a C# dictionary.

Comment: What would be the use for the JSON formatted that way? Would you want to have an array of objects like `{ ColumnName: "FooResult", ColumnValue: 3.123 }`

Comment: Your current expected JSON result is invalid because field names are duplicated.

Comment: The reason I want the JSON in that format is I am consuming it with an AJAX call and then rendering it visually. To do this I need to identify for the visualization script what is a value to be graphed and what is a category(name) to be placed along an axis. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification I've only been on the .NET stack for a short time I'll remember to keep those separate.

Comment: @Alexander: So can't you reformat the data on the JavaScript side before you render it?  That wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Alexander, please include your View's Ajax call. That is where your de-serializing should happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you've forgotten to add `{` & `}` between each pair of `ColumName`, `ColumnValue`, and serialze it as an array.

On the contrary, your JSON is not valid or is not JSON, because you're repeating the same property name many times.

If I'm right this is a test case that shapes a Dictionary the way you want:

```
[TestClass]
public class CustomDictionaryJsonSerialization
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SerializeDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict
            = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"col1", 1}, {"col2", "two"}};

        var nameValues = dict.Keys.Select(k =>
            new {ColumnName = k, ColumnValue = dict[k]});

        var toSerialize = new {a = nameValues.ToList()};

        string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSerialize);

        Assert.IsNotNull(serialized);
    }
}
```

The obtained `serialized` value is like this:

```
{"a":
  [ { "ColumnName":"col1", "ColumnValue":1 },
    { "ColumnName":"col2", "ColumnValue":"two" } ]
}
```